How to cover up hole in stucco wall
I made a 1/2” hole in my garage’s exterior stucco wall to run a decorative light wire. How can I cover it up such that I can easily move the wire? What I found online involves applying silicone and grout which will seal the wires also. Any suggestions?


what do you mean by cover?

If you are moving the wires then they won't need sealing...

@jsotola cover meaning close the hole in a way that I can easily remove it and put it back when necessary. Purpose it to avoid any moisture leak,  heat leak, insects coming through etc.

Can you confirm what voltage that cable is?  You're not supposed to run 120V through walls like that.  If it's low-voltage wiring, that's OK.

It’s a 5V DC supply

a stopper made from some sort of closed cell foam like a piece of backing strip.

Plug the holes with rubber stoppers. Then when you need to use the hole again remove the stopper.
